# How to reverse 2d arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

array :

```
int[,] nums = new int[3,4]{
    {6,7,9,8},
    {4,2,1,3},
    {9,7,0,4}
};
```

I need to print out the rows in reverse but keep the columns in same order.

Iooked all over the internet I don't even know where to start my code, all I have is a for loop that prints in reverse but when I run my code nothing shows up.

```
for (row = 3; row >= 0; row--)
{
    for (column = 0; column < 4; column++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ",nums[row,column]);
    }
}
```

I'm definitely missing something and the only error I get is the index out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, you are, 3 rows means indexes from 2 to 0, not 3 to 0.

Comment: You should be getting an exception, not "nothing". Does the rest of the code hide exceptions? That's a *very* bad idea

Comment: You can use [`Array.GetLength(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=net-6.0) to determine the length of each dimension to get the starting and ending values in your loops.

Comment: @juharr Note that `GetLength` would cause problems for (the incredibly rare!) case where an array doesn't start at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do *not* use *magic* numbers like `3`, `4`, but actual array lengths, `GetLength(...)`:

```
      int[,] nums = new int[3, 4] { 
        { 6, 7, 9, 8 }, 
        { 4, 2, 1, 3 }, 
        { 9, 7, 0, 4 }, 
      };

      for (int row = nums.GetLength(0) - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < nums.GetLength(1); ++column)
          Console.Write($"{nums[row, column]} ");

        if (row > 0)
          Console.WriteLine();
      }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3yHt1w)

Comment: No, don't use `nums.GetLength(0) - 1` when you have `nums.GetUpperBound(0)` which is far more suited for this purpose.

Comment: @DavidG: yes, `for (int row = nums.GetUpperBound(0); row >= 0); --row)`  or even `for (int row = nums.GetUpperBound(0); row >= nums.GetLowerBound(0); --row)` can be a good alternative, but `.GetLength(0) - 1`, `.Length - 1`, `.Count - 1` for arrays, lists etc. is a more *general* pattern: say, list doesn't have `GetUpperBound` equivalent that's  why I put it like this

Comment: Except we're not working with List here, this is an array where we are working with the index.

Comment: And for a `List` it's almost always better to use `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

As you know indexes in an array go from 0 to upper bound so when cycling through you should consider that for an array with 3 elements you will have indexes 0, 1 and 2, you are trying to access index 3 which does not exist.

High level languages have safeguards to avoid this, here an out of range type exception is thrown to let you know you are accessing memory that does not belong to the array.

You should avoid direct indexing because it's very easy to get these off-by-one errors, you should always try to use range based loops, if that's not possible get the length of the array by code, don't use hard coded dimensions unless you have to. Here you can use member methods to figure out the bounds of the array:

```
int[,] nums = {
    {6,7,9,8},
    {4,2,1,3},
    {9,7,0,4}
};

for (var row = nums.GetUpperBound(0); row >= 0; row--)
{
    for (var column = 0; column < nums.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ",nums[row,column]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); // line break for tiddy print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```cs
for (row = 2; row >= 0; row--)
{
    for (column = 0; column < 4; column++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ",nums[row,column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP and others would benefit a lot if you add a description on why this answer solves the problem. How indexes start at `0` so it should be `row = 2`.

Comment: You're right, sorry

Comment: No need to apologize, I was only giving you advice on how you can write better answers. Your answer fixes the problem, it is just it could be a bit better.

Comment: this code is the most simplest and defintely works, many thanks, so by starting at 0 the 3 numbers is already accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

> for (**row = 3**; row >= 0; row--)

The program is throwing OutOfRangeEception, because when you have an array[3,4], the last index of row is 2. Your program was trying to find an element with too large index number(3).
Here you have working code

```
int[,] nums = new int[3, 4] { { 6, 7, 9, 8 }, { 4, 2, 1, 3 }, { 9, 7, 0, 4 } };
        for (int **row = 2**; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", nums[row,column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

As you can see, changing value in for loop from 3 to 2 fixed the problem.
And one important note from me - try to declare counter variables inside *for* - do not make it "global" if you don't need to. In bigger project it could use more memory than necessary. When it's inside *for*, garbage collector will destroy the variable after all loops

Comment: much appreciated, thanks for the advice